# is there a way to build meteor mobile app from build.phonegap.com?

Tags: meteor, phonegap-build

I am new to meteor. I developed mobile application from meteor. Now I wish to build that app from build.phonegap.com site. I feel build.phonegap is easy instead of `meteor build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it short its not possible to build an app using the phonegap build service.

The reason for this is `meteor build` does not exclusively build the apk. `meteor build` also takes your project and builds it up into what would be the `/www` directory in your phonegap project.

Secondly Meteor doesn't use the original phonegap/cordova build. There is a modification to phonegap so the files in `/www` are served using an on-device HTTP server at `http://meteor.local`. This is one of the reasons its not available on WP8, Blackberry, etc. The local webserver sorts out some issues related to routing.

So you would need to use `meteor build` to build your app.